# Why array covariance doesn't work for value type?

Tags: c#, arrays, covariance

Consider the following

```
     int a = 10;
     object i=a; // works
     object[] obj=new dog[10];// Works
     object[] obj1=new int[10];//Doesn't work
```

I know array covariance doesn't work for value type? Is it a limitation or is there a good logic behind it? Please forgive me if its a stupid question as I'm a beginner.

Comment: This would require boxing the elements, which changes their representation.

Comment: b.t.w. the runtime allows using an `int[]` as an `uint[]` because it doesn't change the representation. C# doesn't allow this cast, so you'll need to cast to object in between. `uint[] x = (uint[])(object)new int[1];` works.

Comment: Note: that other question uses `IEnumerable<T>` in the example, not `T[]`, but the question and answer both apply to covariance in general.

Comment: @CodesInChaos... I don't get your point

Comment: @hvd... can you provide me the link to other similar question?..and thanks sir I will be downvoted now.. all my hard earned points will be deducted now.:(

Comment: @dividedbyzero It should show up at the top of your question. There are no downvotes on your question (at this time), and I don't see a reason why someone would downvote this just because it's been asked before.

Comment: The array element size is incompatible.  In 64-bit mode, an *object* reference requires 8 bytes.  But an *int* element only takes 4.  It can only be covariant if the element sizes are guaranteed to match, that only works for reference types.  Technically it could have been implemented by auto-generating code that boxes *every* element.  But that would be silly.

Comment: @HansPassant..........but in c# are n't arrays considered as objects?